# Javascript: Array being passed as parameter doesn't retain values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, subset, powerset

I am trying to solve the problem [Subsets](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/) using Javascript. The task is to print the powerset i.e., all subsets from an array. In the function below, I am passing an array as a parameter to collect all the subsets, but when I print, I find all but empty arrays only.

Why doesn't the array *all_sets* retain the elements? How do I modify the function parameter to retain the elements?

```js
function generate(nums, curr_index, temp, all_sets) {
  if (curr_index === nums.length) {
    all_sets.push(temp);
    return;
  }

  temp.push(nums[curr_index]);
  generate(nums, curr_index + 1, temp, all_sets);
  temp.pop();
  generate(nums, curr_index + 1, temp, all_sets);
}

function generateAllSubsets(nums) {
  let all_sets = [];
  generate(nums, 0, [], all_sets);
  return all_sets;
}

let all_sets = generateAllSubsets([1, 2, 3, 4]);
console.log(all_sets);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're **pushing the reference to the `temp`** into `all_sets`. Now since the same `temp` array gets modified in your recursive calls, it ends up being empty(*when result gets constructed when the stack gets emptied in bottom up fashion*) when you push it to `all_sets`. The fix is pretty simple. Push a copy of the `temp` into `all_sets` instead of the reference. Something like:

```js
function generate(nums, curr_index, temp, all_sets) {
  if (curr_index === nums.length) {
    all_sets.push([...temp]); // <--- here
    return;
  }

  temp.push(nums[curr_index]);
  generate(nums, curr_index + 1, temp, all_sets);
  temp.pop();
  generate(nums, curr_index + 1, temp, all_sets);
}

function generateAllSubsets(nums) {
  let all_sets = [];
  generate(nums, 0, [], all_sets);
  return all_sets;
}

let all_sets = generateAllSubsets([1, 2, 3, 4]);
console.log(all_sets);
```